# Pandas operation per date in index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have the following dateframe in Pandas for a number of days for different commodities:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["Bid", "Ask"], index_col='tid')
```

Populated it looks as follow:

```
2015-07-15 07:16:39.034  49.960  50.000
2015-08-12 07:16:39.235  49.958  49.998
```

I need to find rolling mean per day. So I extract the days as such:

```
dates = set(df.index.map(pd.Timestamp.date))
```

Then I iterate thru the dates and calculate the rolling mean:

```
for d in dates:
    df['rm200'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(df[d]['Bid'], window=200), 5)
```

That gives the following error:

> KeyError: datetime.date(2015, 7, 15)

If I add str(d) as such:

```
df['rm200'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(df[str(d)]['Bid'], window=200), 5)
```

The error disappears, but I do not get the rolling mean.

However, if I copy the date from the error and add it, I get the result I want, but for obvious reasons only for the date in question:

```
df['rm200'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(df['2015, 7, 15']['Bid'], window=200), 5)
```

How can I iterate thru the dates and get the operation performed for each date separately?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough data to test, but I'd suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
pd.rolling_mean(df.resample('1B'), window=200)
```

`df.resample('1B')` creates a DataFrame based on weekdays (you can specify an alternative calendar), taking the average value for each day (it is unclear if your data has only one value per day or several).

`pd.rolling_mean` simply takes the rolling mean of the most recent 200 daily observations.

Comment: No, that does not work. I have about 50 000 values per day. By using this method, I understand that it will take the average per day and create a rolling average for the daily averages. I need a rolling average per day. As in calculating the rolling average for the 50 000 datapoints I have for a day, and start all over again the next day, just using the datapoints for that day.

Comment: Your question is far from clear.  I assume you have a number of commodities (e.g. CL, C, ED, etc) and expiration months.  I assume that you need some sort of grouping on these, but it is not clear if you want it on the commodity or the commodity and expiration.  I believe your question is probably too broad as posted, and that you should attempt to simplify it to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. I tried to clearify it and asked it again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158990/pandas-day-for-day