# Pandas day for day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a lot of data in a Pandas dataframe:

```
Timestamp                 Value     
2015-07-15 07:16:39.034  49.960 
2015-07-15 07:16:39.036  49.940 
......
2015-08-12 23:16:39.235  42.958
```

I have about `50 000` entries per day, and I would like to perform different operations on this data, day by day.

For example, if I would like to find the rolling mean, I would enter this:

```
 df['rm5000'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Value'], window=5000)
```

But that would give me the rolling mean across dates. The first rolling mean datapoint August 12th would contain `4999` datapoints from August 11th. However, I would like to start all over each day, so as the first 4999 datapoints on each day do not contain a rolling mean of `5000`, as there might be a large difference between the last data one date and the first data the next day.

Do I have to slice the data into separate dataframes for each date for Pandas to do certain operations on the data for each separate date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the timestamps as a index, you can `groupby` a `TimeGrouper` with a frequency code to partition the data by days, like below

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': pd.date_range('2015-07-15', '2015-07-18', freq='10min'), 
                           'Value': np.linspace(49, 51, 433)})

In [3]: df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

In [4]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window=15))

Out[4]: 
Timestamp
2015-07-15 00:00:00          NaN
2015-07-15 00:10:00          NaN
.....
2015-07-15 23:30:00    49.620370
2015-07-15 23:40:00    49.625000
2015-07-15 23:50:00    49.629630
2015-07-16 00:00:00          NaN
2015-07-16 00:10:00          NaN
```